# Mercurial log for MQ

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I can use `hg log` with either `--stat` or `-p` to see affected files and diff version for the revisions. Is there something like that for patches sitting in MQ ? I would like to see what changes would be brought by a particular patch without applying it first.

Answer (score 0):

Patches which are under mq control but currently not applied are not part of the repository and as such cannot be accessed by the normal mercurial commands.

However the patches are stored as patch files in .hg/patches/ directory, and you can directly view the patch files. The *series* file lists the order in which the patches are going to be applied.

Comment: I understand that. Though, `hg qseries -s` prints me description of the patch which is obviously taken from the patch file. What could be the reason not to have a command that would also get `diff` content and either `cat` it to the screen. I have a bash function that does it, but it doesn't work on Windows.